# Not able to use react-native-calendars

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

> error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `hoist-non-react-statics`
>    from `E:\DEVELOPMENTWORKSPACE\test\node_modules\react-native-calendars\src\expandableCalendar\asCalendarConsumer.js`: Module `hoist-non-react-statics` does not exist in the Haste module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968

To resolve try the following:

1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that src/expandableCalendar/asCalendarConsumer.js is trying to import 'hoist-non-react-statics' which is not declared as a dependency in package.json
So the solution is to add it in package.json as this:

```
"dependencies": {
"lodash": "^4.0.0",
"prop-types": "^15.5.10",
"xdate": "^0.8.0",
"hoist-non-react-statics": "*"},
```

than run `npm install` run `react-native run-ios` and  you're up to go!